# Tracking Overall Progress During Parallel Processing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a DCF built in an Excel worksheet so that users have the flexibility to go and edit the DCF as needed. I iterate through 1,000+ assumption variations in a for loop in Excel VBA. In the process of trying to speed this up I discovered Tom's multithreading idea here: https://analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-vba-multithreading-addin/.

I got that to work and significantly sped up the calculations. Now I'd like to track in a user form the overall progress through the iterations.

I've tried using Chip Pearsons hidden name solution here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/hidden.htm.

Unfortunately when I use that in one of the parallel threads, it breaks.

Within the worker threads I use the below to set a truly global variable to keep track of how many iterations have been completed across the threads. This is what breaks:

```
SetHiddenName "Total_iter", (GetHiddenName("Total_iter") + 1)
```

Hidden Name functions/subs:

```
Public Sub SetHiddenName(Name As String, Value As Variant)
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SET.NAME(""" & Name & """, " & Value & ")"
End Sub

Public Function GetHiddenName(Name As String)
    GetHiddenName = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(Name)
End Function

Sub DeleteHiddenName(Name As String)
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SET.NAME(""" & Name & """)"
End Sub
```

Comment: "breaks" looks like what exactly?

Comment: The break occurs in the worker threads which is vbscript creating additional instances of the Excel application and running a subset of the iterations. Example being if I have 4 threads, it creates 4 additional instances off excel to run their subset. The parallel threads get stuck on that line and you can see CPU usage in task manager drop to zero. It will stay that way indefinitely. It gets stuck in an infinite loop because the parallel threads can't calculate that line. The only reason I know it's that line is because if I comment it out it will execute fully.

Comment: Further, when I force quit the parallel instances I get the following error message from vbs: Error: Unknown runtime error. Code: 800A9C68. Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error.

Comment: No idea about using the hidden names - you could try instead writing out a file from each thread, and having your "master" workbook check for them

Comment: It's not really multithreading in a sense that you have *threads* that you can synchronize.... more like, distributing work across multiple *processes*, each running their own thread in a silo - and now you're trying to synchronize these threads, and they're all bumping into each other and stepping on toes trying to write conflicting information to the same place. Best not even try synchronizing, and instead have each process write its own progress in its own place, and have the "main" instance periodically read (a thread-safe copy of) all these places and add everything up to report.

Comment: I never tried doing this BTW, so take the above with a grain of salt... might work, might not =)